# Canceling onkeypress event after changing focus

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onkeypress

My users want this form to advance focus to the next field when enter is press instead of submitting the form. I've added an `onkeypress` handler to the test input to change the focus when enter is press.

In the code below, when `keydown` function changes focus, I see the cursor jump to the new textbox but then the form gets submitted as if I pressed the enter key again. I thought that by returning false in my event handler the event would not be passed on but that does not seem to be the case. I've seen this behavior in both Chrome and Firefox.

Could someone tell me what I am missing?

```
<form action="" name="confirmation" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <label for="id_event_fuel_amount">Quantity:</label>

            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="event_fuel_amount_id" name="event_fuel_amount" onkeypress="keydown(event, &#39;event_purchase_amount_id&#39;)" />
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <label for="id_event_purchase_amount">Sale:</label>

            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="event_purchase_amount_id" name="event_purchase_amount" />
                
            </div>
        </div>

        
        <input type="hidden" name="state" value="3" id="id_state" />
        
        <input type="hidden" name="time_stamp" value="2011-09-24 14:34:06" id="id_time_stamp" />
        
        <input type="hidden" name="purchase" value="66" id="id_purchase" />
        

        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
    function keydown(e,s){
        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
        else if (e.which) code = e.which;
        if (code==13){
            document.getElementById(s).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is the `onkeypress` attribute really necessary? Binding the event programmatically would be a better option... (because then you wouldn't have to expose your `keypress` function to the global namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
e.preventDefault();
```

That should prevent the event from firing the form submit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('hello').onkeydown=function(e){
    var e=window.event || e;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) return false;
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="hello" />
```

Here is a demo: [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QXDzM/1/)